# Visualforce filtered related list error: Content cannot be displayed: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: controller, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to display a list of contracts on an opportunity. The list should include any contracts associated with the Account on the opportunity OR it's parent account. Despite that fact that a test SOQL return 2 contract records, I'm getting the error:

> Content cannot be displayed: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Here is the visualforce page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="RelatedContracts" tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contracts List" id="ContractId">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contracts}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="ContractName">
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR('/')}{!c.Id}" target="_blank">{!c.ContractNumber}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Status}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.StartDate}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Enddate}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.SpecialTerms}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Description}" />

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

And here is the extension class:

```
public with sharing class RelatedContracts {

    public Opportunity opp {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < Contract > contracts {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelatedContracts(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        opp = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();

    }

    Opportunity oppInfo = [SELECT AccountId from Opportunity WHERE id = : opp.Id];
    Account acct = [SELECT Id, ParentId from Account WHERE id = : oppInfo.AccountId];

    public List < Contract > getContracts() {
        contracts = new List < Contract > ();
        contracts = [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, Status, ContractNumber, StartDate, EndDate, SpecialTerms, Description FROM Contract
            WHERE AccountId = : opp.AccountId OR AccountId = : acct.ParentId
        ];
        System.debug('ContractList' + contracts);
        if (contracts.size() > 0) {
            return contracts;
        } else
            return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plz try defining the oppInfo and acct and null in the class. In the constructor set the values using the soql.
In getContracts() use oppInfo instead of opp variable.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick! I also had to remove the get/set statements in the opp and contracts assignments.